# Ensuring that mypy gets the hint that compared values are always of same types when comparing Unions of multiple types

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing

I get the following traceback that mypy throws:

```
dust/core/validator/_validators.py:504: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("str" and "ValidateProperty")
dust/core/validator/_validators.py:504: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("float" and "ValidateProperty")
dust/core/validator/_validators.py:504: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("float" and "str")
dust/core/validator/_validators.py:504: error: Unsupported operand types for < ("str" and "float")
```

for the code that goes something like following.

```
class Value(ValidateProperty):
    def __init__(min_value: VALUE_RANGE=None, max_value: VALUE_RANGE=None):
        if min_value is not None and max_value is not None:
            if max_value < min_value:
                raise ValueError(f"max_value can not be less than min_value")
```

where `VALUE_RANGE` is

```
VALUE_RANGE = typing.Union[FLOAT,STRING, None]
```

such that:

```
FLOAT = typing.Union[float, "ValidateProperty", None]
STRING = typing.Union[str, "ValidateProperty", None]
```

and `ValidateProperty` is an ABC class with `__get__` and `__set__` methods.

how to ensure that mypy gets that comapred values are always of same types ?

Comment: check the type() before comparison?

Comment: @Ruli I tried it it can work but the cases can increase and it becomes overwork then, any other typing hint workaround ?

Comment: instead you can create a list of types and check if the types are in that list, just an idea

Comment: I think you probably want to use [generics](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#generic-functions). In particular, see [typevars with value restrictions](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generics.html#type-variables-with-value-restriction).